# How can I force close a container in ECS after blue/green deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I deploy my service to ECS container using Fargate. When I update my container it will create a new version of the task and deploy the new version of task to ECS service using blue/green deployment method. Below is an example when I update the application version. You are seeing that there are two tasks in running status. One is the latest version while the other one is the old version marked as INACTIVE. I believe both of the tasks are working in the same time even the old one is INACTIVE. I wonder how I can quickly stop the OLD one. Sometimes both of them exist for 10 minutes long. I don't understand why not stop the old one immediately when the new one is running.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am facing the same issue. Seems like the task that is started by the service creation is not deactivated by the deployment.